# Reading the values set by the stored procedure in SQL Server through C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, t-sql, c#-4.0

I am facing a issue here in reading the values set by a stored procedure in C#.

1. I have a stored procedure which sets variables `@errorCode` `@errorStr` to 0 and "Failed" on failure of a stored procedure.
2. I have a C# function which invokes the Stored Procedure and the value is set correctly but I am not able to read the values of `@errorCode` and `@errorStr` through my C# code.
3. My code goes as follows

---

```
string op = null;

cmd.CommandText = "PopulateAnswers";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@i_xmlreq", SqlDbType.Xml);
param.Value = xmltext;
param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);     
cmd.Connection = Conn1;   
SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (dataReader.HasRows)
{
    op = dataReader.GetValue(1).ToString();

    if (op.CompareTo("Failed To set Answers") == 0)
    {
        WriteErrorLog("Failed to execute the stored Procedure");
        return "1:Failed to execute stored procedure ";
    }
    else
    {
        return "0:success";
    }
}
```

I am getting an error while I am trying to read the data. It says that you are trying to read a value which does not exist. But I am able to see the values properly when I hover over the variable datareader. It's present under Datareader -> Results view -> [0] -> Non-static .

Comment: dataReader.GetValue(1) should be a GetValue(0).  It's 0 based indexing into columns.

Comment: I actually have two columns errorCode and errorStr . So I tried for both , with 0 and 1 . Its not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call dataReader.Read() before you can get the values.

Comment: What I observed was if I change to the following         while(dataReader.Read())
{
    op = dataReader.GetValue(1).ToString();

    if (op.CompareTo("Failed To set Answers") == 0)
    {
        WriteErrorLog("Failed to execute the stored Procedure");
        return "1:Failed to execute stored procedure ";
    }
    else
    {
        return "0:success";
    }
}
This is not working